# Limit email deployment application wide on non-production environments

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I am developing my first Laravel app and want to avoid accidentally deploying emails from my dev and local environments to real people, other than myself. My goal is to have a list of comma-separated email addresses in my .env file that the Laravel's Mailable checks against when APP_ENV is not "production".

```
# .env
APP_ENV=local
EMAIL_WHITELIST=test@example.com
```

I checked the send method in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailable.php and could modify the code there but have an eerie feeling that I am not supposed to touch that file.

```
# vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailable.php
    public function send($mailer)
    {
        $this->withLocale($this->locale, function () use ($mailer) {
            Container::getInstance()->call([$this, 'build']);

            $mailer = $mailer instanceof MailFactory
                            ? $mailer->mailer($this->mailer)
                            : $mailer;

            return $mailer->send($this->buildView(), $this->buildViewData(), function ($message) {
                $this->buildFrom($message)
                     ->buildRecipients($message)
                     ->buildSubject($message)
                     ->runCallbacks($message)
                     ->buildAttachments($message);
            });
        });
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You extend `Mailable`into e.g. `App\Mail\Mailable` and have your own classes inherit from that. Or, just set `MAIL_DRIVER=log` in your dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create an [Event Listener](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events#defining-listeners) and register it with Laravel's `MessageSending` event. This allows you to perform all manner of actions on each outgoing message before it is sent.

**App\Providers\EventServiceProvider**

```php
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending' => [
        'App\Listeners\PrepareMessageForSending'
    ],
];
```

**App\Listeners\PrepareMessageForSending**

```php
class PrepareMessageForSending
{
    public function handle(MessageSending $event)
    {
        if (env('APP_ENV') !== 'production') {
            // for example, you could redirect everything to a mail trap account
            $event->message->setTo('mailtrap@example.com');
        }
 
        return $event->message;
    }
}
```